# How to use tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I want to convert a .csv file to a TF Record. My problem now,         python_io doesn't exists in Tensorflow 2.0.

```py
     writer=tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)
     path = os.path.join(FLAGS.image_dir)
     examples = pd.read_csv(FLAGS.csv_input)
     grouped = split(examples, 'filename')
     for group in grouped:
        tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
        writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())
     writer.close()
     output_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), FLAGS.output_path)
```

```
I get this error:
File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 102, in <module>
main()
File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 89, in main
writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python_io'
```

What do i have to use instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the official [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/TFRecordWriter), the `python.io` package has been moved to a new one called `io`. Just swap them and it works.

```
writer = tf.io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In TF 2.0 `tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter()` has been changed to `tf.io.TFRecordWriter()`

Answer (score 0):

Tf.io.TFRecordWriter is the official way to write tfrecords for small data sets. You can also try apache beam to parallelize the conversion from CSV to tfrecords to larger CSVs.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)

with tf.io.TFRecordWriter('data.tfrecords') as file_writer:

    x = tf.random.normal([100, 1])
    y = tf.random.normal([100, 1])

    feature = {
    "x": tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=x.numpy().astype(np.float))),
    "y": tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=y.numpy().astype(np.float)))
    }

    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
    record_bytes = example.SerializeToString()
    file_writer.write(record_bytes)
    print(record_bytes)
```